# Gitlab registry...unable to login not running?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Followed the gitlab-registry guide to get it running (and enabled to project)

I know the HTTPS works fine (TLS via letsencrypt) because when i login to my gitlab, it successfully redirects to https.

when attempting to login to docker however:

docker login (my domain)

i am getting:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

netstat -tulpn shows that registry running on 4567

but completely unable to connect to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have docker installed on the machine you are running `docker login` from. And if it's installed, you need to be `root` or in the `docker` group.